# How to make marshmallow ice cream topping without it hardening in the icecream

Tags: marshmallow

My favorite flavor icecream is chocolate marshmallow swirl but the only brand I know of that makes it is Turkey Hill and I can't find it outside of Pennsylvania. I live in California now so that's a problem. I've tried to add my own kind of marshmallow topping but it always hardens in the icecream. Does anyone have a remedy for this? Thank you

Comment: Interestingly, The Perfect Scoop (the only ice cream book I have which includes topping recipes) gives no swirl-in recipe for marshmallow, but a sauce recipe which is meant to be prepared and spooned on the ice cream right before serving. If it turns out that a swirl-in  is difficult to achieve, you might decide to go the sauce route.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this mentioned on the internet a couple of times...it's not a topping, so you won't get the "swirl", but a way to add marshmallow into your ice cream, like in rocky road.

Take regular sized marshmallows and knead them between your fingers until you get a soft pliable mass.  Reserve on a plate until you have enough for your batch.  When the ice cream is almost frozen, mix them in.  Sounds like it takes a bit of work, but supposedly they don't freeze solid after this point.

Comment: I wonder if heating them briefly in the microwave and mashing with a spoon would work similarly? Mushing them with your fingers deflates them more than anything, and also makes them sticky and stretchable if you continue. Which is all to say that a swirl is still doable, I think.